# Espresso UI test on Android Floating Action Button menu items

Tags: android, android-espresso, floating-action-button

I'm using futuresimple's [Android Floating Action Button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button). I'd like to use Espresso to create UI tests that interact with it. `multiple_actions` is just the button that opens the Floating Action Button (FAB) menu. `draw_fab` is one of the floating action buttons that appears when you click `multiple_actions`. Clicking `draw_fab` starts a new android activity and in this activity I wish to press a standard button with the id `componentMenuButton` (that itself brings up a menu).

```
@Test
public void simpleCircuitTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.multiple_actions)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.draw_fab)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.componentMenuButton)).perform(click());
    // other stuff...
}
```

When I run this test I see that the first click works and the floating menu buttons display. However the call to click `draw_fab` seems to have zero affect and as such I get a `No views in hierarchy found matching: with id...` error when the call to click `componentMenuButton` is reached.

This is where I get confused.

```
@Test
public void simpleCircuitTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.draw_fab)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    View v = mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.draw_fab);
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(v.getVisibility()==v.VISIBLE));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(v.isShown()));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(v.isEnabled()));

    onView(withId(R.id.multiple_actions)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.draw_fab)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(v.getVisibility()==v.VISIBLE));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(v.isShown()));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(v.isEnabled()));
}
```

Above is my attempt to figure out what is going on. When I run this test even though I have not yet clicked the `multiple_actions` FAB, `isDisplayed` passes and all the log output is true. And then in the next segment Espresso clicks `multiple_actions` and again all the output is true. So it is as if performing the click on `multiple_actions` to bring up `draw_fab` for clicking has zero impact whatsoever on the test passing. This is not how it should be?

My hunch now is that the repo I'm using for floating action buttons simply doesn't support Espresso use? That or there's something special about FABs or something basic about Espresso that I'm missing. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I look at my `activity_home.xml` for the activity I'm trying to test I have the following for the FABs (Floating Action Buttons)

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/draw_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_title="Draw Circuit"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_draw"/>
```

So I naturally thought that the id multiple_actions can be used to click the FAB that opens the menu of FABs. However, looking at a `values.xml` I have in my project that was generated by the FAB library I use I see

```
<item name="fab_expand_menu_button" type="id"/>
```

This likely comes from [here](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/aadc751e118d7f8f1b7f26b814b10c653e00007b/library/src/main/res/values/ids.xml). Using this ID (which I didn't write) instead, everything is fixed. I assume the FAB id is hard-coded for the top level one.

```
@Test
public void simpleCircuitTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.fab_expand_menu_button)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.draw_fab)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.componentMenuButton)).perform(click());
    // other stuff...
}
```

More interestingly, when I use `multiple_actions` I figured out it presses elsewhere on the screen (didn't realize since there was no visual feedback, but then I placed a `HorizontalScrollView` to take up the entire screen and sure enough I see Espresso clicking it), which makes sense of why those log values always returned true. The values are true for another element on screen that isn't tied to being visible or not from clicking the FAB